# Detect client platform with Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

In my project I want to let admins access data from a web page and common users access from mobile app.

I read Firebase lets create a custom token to add fields to the standard token, but the web app (which should declare the privilege of the user) achieves this [through node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), which i don't know.

Does anyone know a simple way to distinguish between users by the platform they use?
Can you suggest me any different approach?

Creating a custom token only on the Android/iOS device doesn't seem to me a good approach, since permits anyone to have admin privileges simply by skipping my apps.

Comment: People could be using your app from any platform at any time.  Making the assumption that a user is only using your app on a single platform all the time is probably not a very good idea.

Comment: But only admins can access from the web and admins can only access from the web, I'd like to use this as distinctive. I just need to know whether a use is admin or not

Comment: You can store custom data about the user in Realtime Database.  Authentication is not really a flexible data storage mechanism.

Comment: What do you mean? What kind of custom data would you suggest?

Comment: Maybe a boolean indicating whether or not the user is an admin?

Comment: No, because this would give the admin the rights to access the database with full powers even from mobile app (in case he also is a common user), and I should filter data on the client. That's why I'm looking for a way to filter by platform